# Solving a non-linear first order differential equation with only simple terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Below is a problem I did. My check shows the answer is wrong. I suspect that I made a silly algebra error. Where did I go wrong?

Problem:
Solve the following differential equations.
$$ ( 3x + y + 1 ) dx - ( 3x + y ) dy = 0 $$

Answer:

I am going to use the substitution $z = 3x + y + 1$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{dz}{dx} &= 3 +  \frac{dy}{dx} \\
dz &= 3 \, dx + dy \\
dy &= dz - 3 \, dx \\
z dx - ( z - 1)(dz - 3 dx) &= 0 \\
z \, dx &= ( z - 1)(dz - 3 dx) \\
z \, dx &= (z-1) \, dz - 3(z-1) \, dx \\
z \, dx &= (z-1) \, dz - 3z \, dx + 3 \, dx \\
(4z - 3 ) \, dx &= (z-1) \, dz \\
dx &= \frac{z-1}{4z-3} \, dz \\
\end{align*}
Using an online integral calculator, I find:
$$ \int \frac{z-1}{4z-3} \, dz = \frac{z}{4} - \frac{\ln{|4z-3|}}{16} +  C_1 $$
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{z}{4} - \frac{\ln{|4z-3|}}{16} +  C_1 \\
16x &= z - \ln{|4z-3|} + C_2 \text{ where } C_2 = 16C_1 \\
16x &= 3x + y + 1 - \ln{|4z-3|} + C_2 \\
16x &= 3x + y - \ln{|4z-3|} + C \text{ where } C = C_2 + 1 \\
13x &= y - \ln{|12x + 4y + 1|} + C \\
\end{align*}
Now to check the answer, I differentiate both sides.
\begin{align*}
13 &= \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{12 + 4 \, \frac{dy}{dx}}{12x+4y+1} \\
13( 12x+4y+1 ) &= ( 12x+4y+1 )\frac{dy}{dx} - 12 - 4 \, \frac{dy}{dx} \\
156x + 52y + 25 &= ( 12x+4y+1 )\frac{dy}{dx} - 4 \, \frac{dy}{dx} \\
\end{align*}
This answer does not check.

Comment: should be $16x=\color{red}4z$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a correction of the working following your (correct) integration.

$\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{z}{4} - \frac{\ln{|4z-3|}}{16} +  C_1 \\
16x &= 4z - \ln{|4z-3|} + C_2 \text{ where } C_2 = 16C_1 \\
16x &= 12x + 4y + 4 - \ln{|4z-3|} + C_2 \\
4x &=  4y +4- \ln{|4z-3|} + C \text{ where } C = C_2 + 1 \\
x &= y +1- \frac{1}{4}\ln{|12x + 4y + 1|} + C \\
\end{align*}$

This now gives the correct derivative.

Answer (score 0):

$$(3x+y+1)dx−(3x+y)dy=0$$
Fraction method is simple here;
$$\frac {dx} {(3x+y)}=\frac {dy}{(3x+y+1)}$$
$$\frac {d(y-x)} {1}=\frac {d(3x+y)}{(12x+4y+1)}$$
$$4{d(y-x)} =\frac {d(3x+y)}{(3x+y+ \frac 1 4)}$$
Integrate:
$$4{(y-x)}+K =\ln|{12x+4y+1}|$$